# Discord.js How to send message author in express using sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, discord.js, steam

I have been coding a discord bot which allows you to do !v which creates an express page which uses a random generated key to link your steam account to your discord account. So far everything is going well other than inserting the steamid into the sqlite table.

I need to have the code get the user who send the !v command and insert the steamid into the table under that user. This is the code I have right now:

```
app.get('/api/auth/:userid', steam.authenticate(), function(req, res) {

    sql.all(`SELECT * FROM info WHERE userid ="${message.author.id}"`).then(rows => {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
    req.params({ "userid": row.key })
    res.redirect('/');
    res.send(req.params);
    })
})

});

app.get('/api/verify/', steam.verify(), function(req, res) {

sql.get(`SELECT * FROM info WHERE userid ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
        if (!row) {
sql.run("INSERT INTO info (key, userid, name, steamid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [rngkey.toString(), message.author.id, message.author.username, req.user.steamid]);
    res.send(req.user).end();

        }
    }).catch(() => {
        console.error;
        sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (key TEXT, userid TEXT, name TEXT, steamid TEXT)").then(() => {
            sql.run("INSERT INTO info (key, userid, name, steamid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [rngkey.toString(), message.author.id, message.author.username, req.user.steamid]);
        });
    });

});
```

[This is what the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KouaW.png)

Would it be possible to get the /:userid (the rngkey) from the auth page and then insert the steamid into that keys row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue by putting that code inside of the client.on, and it worked perfectly.